# how to make a text view selectable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use an adapter to load a list view from a content provider. Each item in the list uses the below layout.

I am looking for a way to make the text view selectable. I have tried using                 `android:textIsSelectable="true"` and `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`, but these make only the text within the text view selectable. I want to make the whole text view itself selectable, instead of only the text within it, so that i can add functions like delete and share to it. Is there some way to achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit :**
As suggested by @kgandroid in the comments,I have used the context menu to partially achieve my desired functionality with the below code. I also removed `android:textIsSelectable"` and `android:selectAllOnFocus` attributes from the item layout file.

```
onCreate(){
    ..
    ...
    lv_chatMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_chat);
    registerForContextMenu(lv_chatMessages);
    ...
}


@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.listview_chat){
            ListView lv = (ListView) v;
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            menu.add("first option");
            menu.add("second option");
        }

    }
```

But i am still not able to do two things :

1. select multiple items in the list view before the context menu appears.
2. have the context menu appear as icons on the top of the screen, similar to what happens by default when text is selected.

Comment: What do you want mean by selectable ?

Comment: You want add Context menu?

Comment: For example, in whatsapp, doing a long touch on any message will select that whole message. A few context options will also appear at the top like delete, share etc. I am aiming for this kind of functionality.

Comment: use context menu on click of an item in the listview

Comment: thanks @kgandroid, i have added an edit to my OP after trying the context menu.

Comment: you cannot select 2 items in a listview at a time.Your second question is not clear to me.

Comment: hmmm..if we cannot select two items in a listview, i wonder how it has been implemented in other apps where multiple items are selected and then an action is chosen.For example, Gmail or watsapp. Regarding my second question - Whenever we do a long click on any text in an android app, few icons like copy, paste etc. appear at the top of the app. I wanted to implement this same kind of behaviour, but when selecting text views, not text. Again, similar to Gmail or whatsapp.